Stargate Graphql query to fetch related record from ASTRA DB
My database is ASTRA DB (Casasndra) and I am using Stargate Graphql gateway to interact with astra DB. For client I am using Postman for query and mutation.
I have created 2 tables using below mutation from postman:
  namespace : createTable(
    keyspaceName: "{{gkeyspace}}"
    tableName: "T_Namespace"
    partitionKeys: [{ name: "namespace_name", type: { basic: TEXT } }]
    clusteringKeys: [{ name: "namespace_id", type: { basic: UUID } }]
    values: [
      { name: "namespace_desc", type: { basic: TEXT } }
      { name: "audit_info", type: { basic: UDT, info: {name:"audit_info"}}}
    ]
  )
  partition : createTable(
    keyspaceName: "{{gkeyspace}}"
    tableName: "T_Partition"
    partitionKeys: [{ name: "partition_name", type: { basic: TEXT } }]
    clusteringKeys: [{ name: "partition_id", type: { basic: UUID } }]
    values: [
      { name: "partition_desc", type: { basic: TEXT } }
      { name: "namespace_id", type: { basic: UUID } }
      { name: "audit_info", type: { basic: UDT, info: {name:"audit_info"}}}
    ]
  )
}

I would like to know the graphql query to fetch records from T_Namespace table and related records from T_Partition table based on namespace_id present in the T_Partition table.

Please help to share graphql query.
Is it a good cassandra table design? if not how to do it?


This is not a properly formulated question. What is the relation between these 2 tables? where is the UDT, index creation steps? What are the access patterns that you want out of this one?
I'm going to refer you to this postman collection that has GraphQL examples and to this GraphQL docs.
